# How to solve preloading fonts error on production?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I everybody,

We're deployed an Nuxt3 [website](https://stage.biomarkers-institute.com/) that works well on local but on AWS EC2 production environment we got this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in 0: "Error: Unable to preload CSS for https://stage.biomarkers-institute.com/_nuxt/default.4789a690.css"
```

Searching we found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348119/nuxt-js-fonts-preload-in-production) but the errors keeps.

Any idea ?

Comment: Ever found the source of the issue ?

Comment: Is there any update?